# How to develop an own operating system for the raspberry pi 4 in c

Tags: pi-4, c, operating-systems

I've seen the Baking Pi tutorials, but they seem to be outdated, because it says they haven't been updated for the pi 2 yet. Also, they only use assembly language,
and I would like to use C instead.
Basically, I'm looking for a turorial on that:

- shows how to write a simple os in C
- covers the raspi 4
- shows how to output text to hdmi
- shows how to read text from the keyboard

Thanks for the help in advance

BTW. I'm not new to c programming

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/Getting_Started

Comment: Due to our policies [What topics can I ask about here?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) **asking for references to online material** is explicitly off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Baking Pi tutorials](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/introduction.html) are outdated if you want to play on Raspberry pi 4 but "it's a free course on building a very simple operating system for the Raspberry Pi in assembly language", [the author Liz Upton said](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/building-a-simple-raspberry-pi-os/).

However, the "jsandler18's tutorial" which hosted on [github - *Building an Operating System for the Raspberry Pi*](https://jsandler18.github.io/) might be helpful.

You are developing an operating system hence it's impossible that there wouldn't any need to coding on ASM. By that, some part of jsandler18's tutorial is on ASM.

Comment: One more question: jsandler18 assumes that I use linux, however my dev pc is a 2011 macbook air running macOS X El Capitan 10.11.6, and some dev tools are hard to get running. Where do I find macos distributions of software like QEMU, which I need for the project? thanks!

Comment: You can run a Linux distribution virtually by "Parallels Desktop" or VMware Fusion".

Comment: You *might* find it easier to use an old-ish PC, and install a decent Linux distro instead of your macbook air. Macs are great for some things, but IMHO they don't age particularly well, or at least lend themselves to running current software.

Comment: @Seamus I don't have a linux pc, but I have another raspberry pi. Can I compile my code on that, then  copy it to the mac so i can put it on an sd?

Comment: @Jake: I don't see why not, but you need to know that's just a guess as I've never tried it myself. It might be a "good thing" as the tool chain that's on the RPi would already be set up for compiling for an ARM target. But if that doesn't work out, there are [some guides for setting up a toolchain to cross-compile for RPi on macos](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cross+compile+for+raspberry+pi+on+macos)